# cognitive bias of this site's userbase

Tags: discussion

A lot of users on this site are amateur musicians, and they want to feel relevant, so they don't want to admit that the best music was made 60 years ago, making them very irrelevant:

https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/105656/did-music-peak-in-1960

It's a kind of cognitive bias that I hope this site will get over (but it probably won't).

Comment: Remember that rock is a tiny fraction of the music that members of this site focus on. More are interested in classical, we have a large number of people who are jazz musicians etc. No genre is better than others - that is entirely opinion based, which is why we do not allow questions like that.

Comment: Your post really is not a question. It seems to be an attempt to annoy others, and is entirely based upon your opinion, which may be correct to you, but is not for the broader musical community here.

Comment: I think the expected reply is: OK Boomer

Comment: The irony of the cognitive bias implicit in this question is hard to fully grasp.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I'm younger than you, judging by the pic.

Answer (score 4):

> A lot of users on this site are amateur musicians, and they want to feel relevant

True.

> they don't want to admit that the best music was made 60 years ago

Also true. We have no time for idle confessions and self-indulgent 'admissions'. Our job right now in 2020 is to make sure that you post again 60 years from now, complaining that no-one admits that the music made in 2020 was the best.

Comment: Just to get a head start: "The best music was made in 2080!" and get off my lawn!

Comment: Such an excellent point. If all musicians were convinced the best music possible was made in 1960, why would we keep making music?

Answer (score 3):

This site at the end of the day is a Music Practice and Theory Q&A site. Not every question about music fits into our site. Questions like this do not fit well in this site for quite a few reasons, but the two reasons that come to mind first are:

1. As worded and as you've seen in the comments to your question, people have very different opinions when it comes to this question. Everyone is entitled to their likes, dislikes, and favorites and the comments everyone had their own favorite year. As a site we are focused on much more objective questions and answers over ones where everyone's opinion is equally valid.
2. Even if we could work out a fully a objective version of this question, this site is more for the people that make music rather than the people who consume it. There is a lot of overlap, but a question like this is much more home in the Music Fans SE.

A little bit more about point 1, the ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?" page](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) highlight several bullet points that suggest when your question may be too subjective. The few I think that can apply to this question are:

> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”